# Problema al mostrar un json campos dublicados

Tags: php, mysql, json

Cuando hago la consulta a mysql desde php y la quiero mostrar en un json me aparecen columnas de mas como campos duplicados

como es que se generan estos campos resaltados en la imágen y como podría hacer para no generar estos ya que en mi base de datos mysql solo están los campos id y descc? [image: en mi base de datos solo existe los campos id y descc pero lo demás lo genera automaticamente cuando quiero mostrarlo en json]

mi codigo es este

```
<?php

function connectDB(){

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tienda_movil");
     if($conexion){
         echo 'La conexión de la base de datos se ha hecho satisfactoriamente <br>';
     }else{
         echo 'Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la conexión de la base de datos';
     }   
     return $conexion;
 }
 function disconnectDB($conexion){

    $close = mysqli_close($conexion);

        if($close){
            echo 'La desconexion de la base de datos se ha hecho satisfactoriamente <br>
';
        }else{
            echo 'Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la desconexion de la base de datos
';
        }   

    return $close;
}

$sql="select*from prueba";
function getArraySQL($sql){
    //Creamos la conexión con la función anterior
    $conexion = connectDB();

    //generamos la consulta

        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8

    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die(); //si la conexión cancelar programa

    $rawdata = array(); //creamos un array

    //guardamos en un array multidimensional todos los datos de la consulta
    $i=0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $rawdata[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    disconnectDB($conexion); //desconectamos la base de datos

    return $rawdata; //devolvemos el array
}

        $myArray = getArraySQL($sql);
        echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso es porque no le indicas que lo quieres solo asociativo fijate en la opción `MYSQLI_ASSOC`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $rawdata[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}
```

para más info en su [documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)